# How to access a hidden field in form in the params value but it says unexpected line end

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, controller, haml, hidden-field

I have a hidden field that I want to permit to my proposal controller.

When I submit the form it says

```
unexpected line end for proposal_params
```

Am I missing something here?

_form.html.haml:

```
%fieldset.col-md-12 = form.label t('.select_tags'), { class: 'tags-label' }
  = form.hidden_field :tags, { class: 'hidden_tags' }
```

controller:

```
def proposal_params 
  params.require(:proposal).permit(:title, :description, :target_audience,
                                   :details, :pitch, :difficulty, :track_id, 
                                   :main_tag_id, comments_attributes: %i[body proposal_id person_id], 
                                   speakers_attributes: %i[person_id id], :tags) 
end
```

Although I am able to access the value by doing  `params[:proposal][:tags]`.

Comment: Try adding `:tags` before array attributes: `permit(..., :tags, comments_attributes: %i[body proposal_id person_id], speakers_attributes: %i[person_id id])`

Comment: I did try that still does not work. I think it has to do with me making use of simple form for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Ruby when calling methods that take positional and keyword arguments you MUST place the keyword arguments last:

```
def foo(*args, **kwargs); end
foo(1, 2, 3, bar: 'baz')
foo(bar: 'baz', 1, 2, 3) # syntax error
```

```
params.require(:proposal).permit(:title, :description, :target_audience,
                                   :details, :pitch, :difficulty, :track_id, 
                                   :main_tag_id, :tags,
                                   comments_attributes: %i[body proposal_id person_id], 
                                   speakers_attributes: %i[person_id id])
```

Comment: I did that. Seems like that works but I am running into another issue : undefined method `each' for "3,4":String . I am submitting the form with 3,4.

Comment: You need to actually split the input into an array of you want to iterate through it

Comment: I guess rails is expecting it to be in an array and I am passing it as a comma separated string.

Comment: If you want to pass an array you need multiple parameters with empty brackets trailing the name. ’foo[bar][]=1&foo[bar][]=2’ . Look at the html output of the collection helpers for an example.

Comment: Or you can just split the string in your controller.